# Not getting correct path from root node to point

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find a path from the root node to a given point but ends up in getting an empty array.In the output I should get List of string of path id's from root to the given point. Please check below link for detailed description about problem.

[Problem Statement](https://docdro.id/X38NJJZ)

I have tried below code to get string id's.

```
public static List<String> findPathToNode(Node rootNode, Point toFind) {
    // @ToDo Implement this routine
    List<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();

    return getAllNodesForPoint(rootNode, toFind, nodeList);   }

  //Recursive function to loop through all nodes of tree and return empty LinkedList   // if point not found or NOT Empty with the path to the point, if point is found

  static List<String> getAllNodesForPoint(Node n, Point p, List<String> list) {
    list.add(n.getId());
    for (Node temp : n.getChildren()) {
      if (temp.getChildren().size() > 0) {
        if (isContained(temp, p)) {
          list.add(temp.getId());
          return list;
        } else {
          getAllNodesForPoint(temp, p, list);
        }
      } else {
        list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(n.getId());
      }
    }
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    return list;   }

  static boolean isContained(Node e, Point p){
    Point topLeft = new Point(e.getLeft(), e.getTop());
    Point topRight = new Point(e.getLeft()+e.getWidth(), e.getTop());
    Point bottomLeft = new Point(e.getLeft(), e.getTop()+e.getHeight());
    Point bottomRight = new Point(e.getLeft()+e.getWidth(), e.getTop()+e.getHeight());
    if(topLeft.getX()<p.getX()
            &&p.getX()<topRight.getX()
            &&topLeft.getY()<p.getY()
            &&bottomLeft.getY()>p.getY()){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }   }
```

Thank you in advanced!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your this part of code fragment

```
for (Node temp : n.getChildren()) {
      if (temp.getChildren().size() > 0) {
        if (isContained(temp, p)) {
          list.add(temp.getId());
          return list;
        } else {
          getAllNodesForPoint(temp, p, list);
        }
      } else {
        list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(n.getId());
      }
    }
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    return list;
```

We can use example given in your problem statement to explain the same.

Example :

```
{"id": "root" ,
"left": 0 , 
"top": 0 ,
"width": 33 , 
"height": 23 ,
"children": [{
               "id": "child-0" ,
                "left": 5 , 
                 “top": 5 ,
                 "width": 20 ,
                 "height": 10 ,
                  "children": []},
               {"id": "child-1" ,
                "left": 10 ,
                "top": 10 ,
                 "width": 20 ,
                  "height": 10 ,
                  "children": []
                }
      ]}
```

It starts with `root` node and in its `children` array there are two childs `child-0` and `child-1` . Because of this it will go in this part of code

```
for (Node temp : n.getChildren())
```

Now this `for` loop will run 2 times , since there are two children of `root` node.

But each  child `children` array is empty so it will fail to go in this fragement of code:

```
if (temp.getChildren().size() > 0)
```

instead, it will go in the `else` part.
But **first issue** is over here. Here, you are initializing an array list every time and adding this children Id.
So, when the loop runs the first time for `child-1` it will create a new list by this

```
list = new LinkedList<>();
```

and add `child-1` to it.
and next time it will again run for `child-2` and reinitialize the list and add `child-2` to it.

So, at the end of `for` loop in our list we will have only 1 entry of `child-2`.

But you are getting empty list as result because after ending for loop you have again reinitialized the list and you are returning empty list.This is the **second issue**.

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
return list;
```

The corrected code of `getAllNodesForPoint` is

```
list.add(n.getId());
    for (Node temp : n.getChildren()) {
      if (temp.getChildren().size() > 0) {
        if (isContained(temp, p)) {
          list.add(temp.getId());
          return list;
        } else {
          getAllNodesForPoint(temp, p, list);
        }
      } else {
        list.add(temp.getId());
      }
    }
    return list;   }
```

Comment: @Prerana Gupta  Now its adding root node 3 times in an array

Comment: In the else part of `for` loop where you are doing  `list.add(n.getId())` you need to do` list.add(temp.getId())`  since `n` refers to starting Node and you are looping through child nodes which are referenced by Node` temp` . Have edited my corrected code of   `getAllNodesForPoint` as well.

Comment: Now its adding all the points in the array root, child0 and child 1 for all points

Comment: You are trying for above example or some other ?

Comment: I am trying different example but the concept is same

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code snippet that would do the job as stated in the Problem statement:

```
private static void getPath(Node root, Point p, List<String> result) {
    if (root != null) {
        result.add(root.getId());
        List<Node> childNodes = root.getChildren();
        if (childNodes != null && !childNodes.isEmpty()) {
            Node child = null;
            for (Node node : childNodes) {
                if (isLeftBoundCondtionMet(node, p) && isTopBoundCondtionMet(node, p)) {
                    child = node;
                }
            }
            getPath(child, p, result);
        }
    }
}

public static Boolean isLeftBoundCondtionMet(Node root, Point p) {
    return root.getLeft() < p.getX() && (p.getX() < (root.getLeft() + root.getWidth()));
}

public static Boolean isTopBoundCondtionMet(Node root, Point p) {
    return root.getTop() < p.getY() && (p.getY() < (root.getTop() + root.getHeight()));
}
```

Comment: Baiser  It is working for all the files except this [link](https://docdro.id/KNwEZun) for one  point [x=32,y=3].  Its showing path node/node-1/node-1-6, But it has to be node/node-1/node-1-6/node-1-6-8/node-1-6-8-4.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on which input set you are referring to? The Id's mentioned in the link is different compared to the result you have specified above.

Comment: Previous ID's were just a small sample to understand the problem. As the problem is the same it should work on all id's of hierarchy. To be precise, it is not working on node id's of [link](https://www.docdroid.net/KNwEZun/input.txt) for the [points](https://docdro.id/GEvHkJR)